# Using AdMob, InMobi...is it possible for a publisher to restrict ads from selected advertisers only in the mobile App?

Tags: android, mobile, admob, ads, inmobi

As in, if publisher wants that ads from selected advertisers only should be shown in the app, how can this be achieved through Google AdMob, InMobi...

Comment: Find a ad network that allows it. This site is for programming problems not a  business research service.

Answer (score 0):

Most ad networks (Admob and InMobi for certain) allow whitelisting of advertisers or, blocking advertisers. That said, it will result in significant no-fills which in turn will result in lower revenues.

A better option might be to block all and only allow certain categories though this will also result in lower fill.